# Manually freeze a dialog in C#

Tags: c#, dialog, progress-bar, backgroundworker

There's a dialog that has a File Save menu command (among others), and there's a BackgroundWorker that executes the saving process (that might take a quite few seconds), disaplays and updates the progress bar, while the dialog is available, and you can still call all other commands interrupting the saving process (leading to file corruption).

Is there a way to manually freeze the dialog while still displaying the progress? Without BachgroundWorkers and progressbars it does freeze and prevent all the dangerous activity, but I'd like it to also have a progress reporter of some kind.

Note that I'm not spawning a separate modal dialog for the progressbar, it's put in my primary dialog I'm talking about.

Comment: Code please.... BackgroundWorker has a [ProgressChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged(v=vs.110).aspx) event specifically for this kind of work (updating UI interface) and it seems that you are not using it....

Comment: `_saveBackgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += (s, e) => { SavingProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage; };` I'm not sure we mean the same thing, I don't think it can update the progressbar without actually updating the dialog.

Comment: The entire point of a dialog is to freeze user input.  Disabling all the other windows and only permitting access to the dialog controls.  If any of them are "dangerous" then you should remove them.  If the dialog does not disable other windows then you are doing it wrong, don't display UI on a worker thread.

Comment: My BackgroundWorker puts the progressbar in the dialog itself, it doesn't spawn a separate (modal) progress dialog like in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to do it seems to be to use a modal window and report progress there, it will completely ban any activity with the main window.